# Why ajax cancel?

Tags: ajax

on some pages that not defined at router some requests canceled. But on other pages all is fine. chrome://net-internals/#events
 [image: show that]

Comment: why do you think its a backbone or marionette?

Comment: Maybe not and thats server side

Comment: Looks like you have set a `timeout` for your request with a low value around 8ms.